# Can I change the notification email sent when transferring a record to a new owner?

Tags: email, workflow, email-template, email-alert

Is it possible to change the contents of the email that is sent to the new owner of a record when someone transfers ownership and checks the 'Send Notification Email' box?

I would like to provide my own email template for this.

Ideally I'd like to be able to specify a template for a specific object such as opportunity and leave all the other objects untouched.

Is my only option to implement the same notification functionality via a workflow email alert. If so how do I prevent the users from also sending the 'standard' notification email?

Comment: Are you referring to sendemail button on the activities related to the object

Comment: @rao No I'm referring to the check box that appears on the page that opens when you click on the 'Change Owner' link next to the opportunity owner field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like the Account Owner change template is not something you can customize...

Quoting this page :
http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/account_owner.htm

"For cases in Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, and Developer Edition organizations, the email text is determined by the Case Assigned Template setting specified in the Support Settings. For other records, the email text is automatically generated and cannot be customized."

So case : yes, leads or accounts : no...

PS. Only if you create a new workflow

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h0edAAA